# How to implment an array of FieldSets in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I've got a custom object (Parts Order) that creates a parts order. Each line item has 3 fields (Part Type, Quantity and Part Number) and for each Parts Order, there can be up to 10 line items. I can't seem to find a good way to implement this. I guess one way would be to create 30 separate fields, but I can't help feeling that there has to be a better way. I could put the 3 fields into a fieldset, but is there a way to put an array of FieldSets to be input on a page?  If there are any other suggestions, I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Do you have a separate object for Parts Order Line Item? It sounds like that is what you need.

Comment: grigriforce - you're spot on here, I recommend you write that up as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to 'FieldSets', you can output them in VisualForce by looping as follows:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Object__c.FieldSets.FieldSet1}" var="f">
<apex:outputField value="{!currentObject[f]}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!currentObject[f]}" required="{!f.required}" />
</apex:repeat>

<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Object__c.FieldSets.FieldSet2}" var="f">
<apex:outputField value="{!currentObject[f]}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!currentObject[f]}" required="{!f.required}" />
</apex:repeat>

<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Object__c.FieldSets.FieldSet2}" var="f">
<apex:outputField value="{!currentObject[f]}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!currentObject[f]}" required="{!f.required}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Where `FieldSet1..n` is the name of the fieldsets associated with the current objecttype for the page, and `Object__c` could be any standard or custom sObject

You can mix and match any subset of "rendered" not "rendered" depending on `recordtype` or any other criteria you have for creating that object.

However, the comment about creating a 2nd object might be more concise, just remember that reporting across multiple object relationships is kind of difficult.

*If your using Standard VF pages, maybe I would suggest using multiple record types, each with their own page layouts*.

Answer (score 0):

Since one Parts Order may have many line items you should create a Parts Order Line Item object that is a child of Parts Order (just like Opportunity and OpportunityLineItem).

To see how to create a multi-edit page so that people can easily add/edit multiple Line Items at once you should check out the excellent [visualforce list controller example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_controller_sosc_edit_data.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/pages_controller_sosc_edit_data.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) in the docs.

Comment: I truly appreciate all the feedback! I did create a separate line item object as a related list, but I didn't

Comment: (oops) carry it to the next level. I will be reading through all the suggested documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As grigriforce said, you need a Line Item custom object to represent the relationship between the order and the item being ordered. This kind of object is called a custom junction object. Using custom junction objects is much more scalable than having 10 lookup fields; what if you need 20 lines next year? You can run out of lookup fields very quickly.

The current force.com workbook walks you through creating exactly this kind of warehouse app. The Line Item object is explained in tutorial 2, step 2. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/index.htm